# For loop PHP to check the value and take if condition is met

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I have to write a php loop. How best to do. Bsically I have 3 purchase lines.

1. qty 3
2. qty 4
3. qty 6

I need a total of 9 qty. So I have to loop through each of above rows and get 9 qty . how to write the loop. Is it for loop or while loop?

1. take line 1. 3 is less than 9 so take whole 3. Line 1 becomes 0 balance.
2. take line 2. 3+4=7 less than 9 so take whole 4. Line 2 becomes 0 balance.
3. take line 3. 7+6 = 13 more than 9. So take only what's required. That is 9-7=2. 7+(9-7) = 9. Line 3 becomes 4 units balance.

I have bee trying for loop with if conditions. Quite not getting there.

Comment: can you share with us what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$items = [3,4,6]; //can also be used as an associative array with "item1" => 3 likewise
$requiredQuantity = 9;
$currentQuantity = 0;

$i = 0; //incrementor
foreach ($items as $item){
    if(($currentQuantity+$item) < $requiredQuantity){
        $currentQuantity += $item;
        $items[$i] = 0;
    }
    elseif(($currentQuantity+$item) == $requiredQuantity){
        $currentQuantity += $item;
        $items[$i] = 0;
        break;
    }
    else{
        $shortageQuantity = $requiredQuantity - $currentQuantity;
        $items[$i] -= $shortageQuantity;
        $currentQuantity += $shortageQuantity;
        break;
    }
    $i++;
} //end of foreach loop

print_r($items); //resultant items list.
```